# Batch script to copy SPECIFIC FILE from network folder to drive D:\

Tags: batch-file

I'm newbie in batch script.  How to write a script on copying specific file from a network folder to my drive `D:\`

Example:

The filename is `ABC021318X.zip`, where `021318` is a date while `ABC` and `X` are constants.  When the script is running it will prompt user to enter the date with a format of `mm/dd/yy`, then when I hit Enter, it will copy `ABC(specified date)X.zip` from a network folder to `D:` drive

Further, when file is not found, it will give a message:

> FILE NOT FOUND!

Hoping someone with the relevant knowledge can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why ask for `mm/dd/yy`, if you need `mmddyy`?

Comment: I want the user to enter the date cautions.

Comment: What for? you don't need them. Ask them for what you need, it's less typing for them too!

Comment: If not possible, it is Ok with me...  Since I accepted Gerhard Barnard's answer.  Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do:

```
@echo off
set /p "mydate=Please Enter date (MMddYY) : "
set "mydate=%mydate:/=%"
copy /Y Z:\AB%mydate%X.zip D:\
```

Where `Z:\` is the network drive in this case.
Note, in this case users can add the date as `MMddYY` i.e `021418` or `MM/dd/YY` i.e `02/14/18` as it will strip out `/` if it exists.

Automatically, if file is not found, it will print error

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Gerhard,  can i ask something if it is Ok?  "set /p "  stands for what? Sorry for poor knowledge in batch script, i just want to know its control/connection/procedure.  Hope you don't mind....

Comment: for more on the set command do `set /?` from cmdline. but to answer your question `/p` is to prompt user for input, the input is then set as the variable, in this case the variable is called `%mydate%` for more on any other command in batch type `help` on cmdline and for each of the commands that interest you just run it with the `/?` switch. i.e `for /?` `if /?` etc.